# Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes, hook-woocommerce

[image]

I have changed dropdown to radio button using [wc-variations-radio-buttons-master](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-variations-radio-buttons)
The different color is also actually radio button.

The current [link](http://dev.lifeformchairs.com/product/this-product-2390/) product have `12` such variation which have product and not other. Some combination I can explain such as `Silver,Matching upholstery,VC,RegularSeat` and `Silver,Matching upholstery,ACC,RegularSeat` have product while `Silver,Matching upholstery,Regular,RegularSeat` have not product now i want to hide `Regular` option from current scenario `and all other such option which have not product`.

I meant to show those radio button which have product if not then hide irrelevant radio button

Product [link](http://dev.lifeformchairs.com/product/this-product-2390/)

Comment: All other product have variation but for this special product i can hardcode if any solution found

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are looking for. Can you make your question clearer or provide an example?

Comment: I have modified my question please check now @Shawn

Comment: You have to draft your own algorithms to check what desired result you want to show for what options the user has selected.

1. Before user comes to the detail page of the product, you need to implement a check that the selection he made, does there are products in the selection or not.
2. Similar will be other cases Silver,Matching upholstery,VC,RegularSeat etc

Comment: please add product of all category @Coder

Comment: I have updated my link now click on link @SavanDholu

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question correctly, you want woocommerce to prevent users from selecting certain combinations of options on variable products, unless a variation with the selected options actually exists and is in stock?

This probably is due to the **woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold**. If your product contains more variations than the threshold specifies, woocommerce will wait until all variation options have been selected by the user before determining if the selected combination of options is valid(in stock, exists, etc).  If the user has selected a combination that is not valid or is not instock, you will get the

> **Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination**

Say you had a product where you can set the following attributes:

**upholstery, base, arms headrest, back**

That is **5** different attributes.
If each one of those attributes has **5** options, that is **25** different possible combinations assuming the user **has to** select all **5** options.
If the user doesn't have to select all **5** options then there are even more possible combinations.

So even if you only actually created **2** variations for this product, its **woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold** would be **25**, meaning **25** possible options(variations).

I think by default the **woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold** is set to **10**.

So to fix(*filter*) this, set the **woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold** to a higher value. If your product has 30 possible combinations(whether they actually exist or not) set the threshold to something higher than 30, like 1111 for example.

You can use the snippet below in your functions.php file.

```
 /* Increase Woocommerce Variation Threshold */
 function wc_ajax_variation_threshold_modify( $threshold, $product ){
  $threshold = '1111';
  return  $threshold;
 }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold','wc_ajax_variation_threshold_modify', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I cannot believe more people haven't run into this situation.

Comment: Thank you - ran into this issue with bulk uploading variations through a csv. After lots of messing about in the csv thinking it was how I was importing the data. I didn't think this would be the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Please check variation matrix table, for correctly matched select of all variants with each other....

Eg.

2x2 means 
11 12
21 22

3x3

111 122 113
221 222 223
331 332 333

Answer (score 0):

One of the quirks in WooCommerce that causes this sort of situation is not having prices on all of your variations, the system does not always tell you that it is required so unexpected things can happen. Please check your variation data and make sure all variations have a price.

Answer (score 0):

"By default, if a Variable product has fewer than 30 variations, the dropdowns for selecting variations on the frontend will be dynamic."

https://woocommerce.com/document/change-limit-on-number-of-variations-for-dynamic-variable-product-dropdowns/